# paket.bootstrapper.exe exited with code 3

Tags: c#, github, bootstrapper

When compiling my C#-project referencing a project cloned from [CommandLine](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline) I get this error:

> Error 2   The command "ClassLibGenerator.paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe"
>   exited with code 3

However when I use the VS-solution provided within the clone and compile the `CommandLine`-project there everything works fine.

Both solutions - mine and the one from the clone - contain the same project - `CommandLine`.

I can´t finf what the error-code means nor do I know why bootrtrapper is needed or what it actually does in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is of any use, but had a similar problem with "paket.bootstrapper.exe exited with code 216", there were also a load of missing references (see later). This was the only SO question I saw so hopefully this may be of use to someone.

Paket is a package manager which is a kind of suped-up NuGet. bootstrapper.exe is a program which downloads the latest manager.

http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/bootstrapper.html

What I did to fix my problem was to go to Tools->Extensions and Updates->Online and install Paket. Restarted Visual Studio, and tried to recompile. This time it resolved my missing references, but still had the 216 error. Turns out this is 32-64 bit compatability error. I downloaded the newest version of  "paket.bootstrapper.exe" from 
https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/releases, overwriting the existing bootstrapper.

This got me compiling again :)